# system(command) returns 2304 in C. But why?

Tags: c, system

I am trying to write a program for opening zip files, by brute force. 
However, I have problem, I keep getting this code back from the system call: 2304. But I can not see why it happens and why the command is not preformed. My code is C. So can anyone guide me to are solution?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h> // For checking file exist

int crack(char* cmd, char* pass, char* file){
    int size = strlen(cmd) + strlen(pass) -1 + strlen(file) + 2;
    int result = -1;
    char* fullcmd = malloc(size);
    strcpy(fullcmd, cmd);
    strncat(fullcmd, " ", 1);
    strncat(fullcmd, pass, strlen(pass) -1 );
    strncat(fullcmd, " ", 1);
    strcat(fullcmd, file);
    //printf("Full Command: %s\n", fullcmd);
    result = system(fullcmd);
    //printf("Result: %d\n", (int) system(fullcmd));
    free(fullcmd);
    return result;
}


void setup(char* cmd, char* file){

    //Read passwords
    FILE* fp;
    char* pass = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read;

    fp = fopen("passwords.txt", "r");
    if(fp == NULL){
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while((read = getline(&pass, &len, fp)) != -1){
        printf("trying password: %s\n", pass);
        if(crack(cmd, pass, file) != -1){
            printf("FILE cracked\n");
            //break;
        }

    }

    fclose(fp);
    if(pass){
        free(pass);
    }
}

//unzip -p password filename

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char *file = argv[1];

    if(access(file, F_OK) == -1){
        printf("Something went wrong \n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    setup("unzip -p", file);

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

The password.txt file, contains all combination of numbers from 0000 to 9999.

- Thanks

Comment: Reading [the `system` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) might help.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I have read it, should have written that sorry. I still can't figure out what my system call fails. Though I might have missed something. But from different examples on the web, I think I am doing it correctly

Comment: The error seems to be return of the command being executed.
Can you try to print the full command, try to execute it manually and check the result status?

Comment: But it *doesn't* fail, because then `system` would have returned `-1` or `127`. If you read the [`RETURN VALUE` section](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html#RETURN_VALUE) it will tell you that the returned value is not what the command returned, not exactly, and you need to use the macros described in [the `waitpid` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html) to get the actual return value.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg ahh thank you will do, however I still do not understand why the command is not performed :)

Comment: You are not `malloc`ing enough space so you cause a buffer overflow which leads to undefined behaviour. Instead of all that calculation and strncat garbage, use `snprintf`.

Comment: By the way, allocate one character to little for the `fullcmd` variable, you forget to allocate space for the zero-terminator which means you write out of bounds which leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) and that makes your whole program ill-formed.

Comment: @MattMcNabb I have checked that the command is at it should be, but I will take another time thank you :)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg thank you :) I will take a look on it all and make it work :)

Comment: You should shift the status to get the "real" value returned because 1 bit is used for the core dump status, in that case the value returned is 9 (2304 >> 8), which in the unzip help page means: the specified zipfiles were not found.

http://www.info-zip.org/mans/unzip.html

Comment: Thanks every one for the help :)